# How can there be a target class problem, when there is no class reference?

Tags: java, replit

So while searching the error message I had when running my code, it talked about target class reference, here is the error message: (I use replit and am writing in java)

```
 java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main
Hello world!
```

Here is the code:

```
class Somme { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long somme = 0;
for(long i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
  if ((i/100)%10 != 3 && (i/100)%10 != 2 && i%3 != 0); { 
    somme = somme + i ;
}
}
System.out.println (somme);
  }
}
```

I don't reference anything but the variable 'somme' and 'i', so I don't understand how I can have a reference error message. This is a standalone code and in my research, the error message seemed to talk about when you have more than one files for a project. Am I wrong? Any push in the right direction is appreciated. I am clearly confuse, but don't know what I am confused about.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048675/deploy-java-on-heroku-cannot-find-main-class-in-target-dependency) user that had the same error message as me. However their problem seemed to be because of multiple files. I did not saw other explanation that seemed to fit with my code.

Comment: Did you forget to post the error message?

Comment: No? It's this : java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main
Hello world!

Comment: Replit requires your class to be called Main not Somme.

Comment: Omg! It work! Thank you! I will know now for the future.

Comment: That's not an error message. That just looks like Repl.it running another class, `Main` (not `Somme`), and producing the output `Hello world!`.

Comment: Now that I work, I see that it was there anyway, I thought it was the error. Thank you for your time!